Still getting cors error after adding @CrossOrigin annotation
I'm having troubles with the CORS error.
I'm trying to post a file to the database but using another endpoint in the same backend application where I post other data from another endpoint. Here's the error:

CORS Missing Allow Origin

Here's the backend controller for the first endpoint:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/v1/file")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class filecontroller {
@Autowired
private final FileSystemStorageService filesService;

public filecontroller(FileSystemStorageService filesService) {
    this.filesService = filesService;
}



@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<responseMessage> uploadFiles(@RequestParam MultipartFile file){
    String message = "";
    try{
        filesService.store(file);
        message = "File Uploaded successfully: "+file.getOriginalFilename();
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new responseMessage(message));
    }catch (Exception e){
        message = "Could not upload the file: "+file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new responseMessage(message));
    }
}

//other methods



}

Here's the controller for the other endpoint:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/user")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UserController {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}


//other methods


@PostMapping
public void registerNewUser(@RequestBody UserClass user){
    userService.addNewUser(user);
}
//other methods



}

Here's my upload file component in Angular:
 constructor(private route: Router, private files: PostFileServiceService) { }

  public main(){
   this.username = localStorage.getItem('user_name');
   }
  public onChangeFile(event: any){
   this.formData = new FormData();
   this.file = event.target.files[0];
    if(this.file){
      this.name = this.file.name;
      this.size = this.file.size;
      this.type = this.file.type;
      this.formData.append('fileSize', this.size);
      this.formData.append('fileType', this.type);
      this.userName = this.username;
      this.formData.append('userName', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.userName)], {type: 'multipart/form-data'}));
      this.nameOfficial = this.name;
      if(this.nameOfficial.includes(" ")){
        this.nameConcat = this.nameOfficial.split(" ").join("");
      }
      this.formData.append('fileName', this.nameConcat ? this.nameConcat : this.nameOfficial);
     }else if(this.file==null){
      return
    }    
  }
  public onSubmit(){
     this.requestSub = this.files.postFile(this.formData).subscribe((resp)=>{
       if(resp==null){
         this.subscribed = true;
         this.toCongrats('fileSuccessfull');
      }
    })
  }
  //other methods

The uploading user component:
public onSubmit(form: NgForm){
this.name = form.value.FullName;
this.surname = form.value.Surname;
this.birthday = form.value.birthday;
this.email = form.value.eMail;
this.nickname = form.value.Nickname;
this.password = form.value.Password;
this.pasDue = form.value.passwordDue;
if(this.pasDue!=this.password){
  this.samePassword=true;
}
let user_name = this.nickname;
if(!user_name){
  this.notNickname=true;
}
let birth = this.birthday;
if(!moment(birth).isValid()){
  this.wrongDate=true;
}
let eMail = this.email;
if(!eMail.includes('@')){
  this.fakeEmail=true;
  return
}
let name = this.name;
let surname = this.surname;
let password = this.password;
if(!password){
  this.notPassword=true;
}
this.requestSub = this.fetchUsers.postUsers(user_name, password, name, surname, birth, eMail)
.pipe(catchError(err=>{
  return throwError(()=>{
    let error = new Error(err).message.toString();
    if(error.includes('500')){
      this.emailAlreadyExist=true;
    }
  });
}))
.subscribe((resp)=>{
  if(resp==null){
    this.Destination('subscribed');
  }
})
 }
//other methods

my services, for posting the user:
public postUsers(user_name: string, password: string, name: string, surname: string, birth: Date, eMail: string): Observable<any>{
const body = JSON.stringify({ user_name, password, name, surname, birth, eMail })
const httpOtions ={
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
  })
};
 const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user?user_name=${user_name}&password=${password}&name=${name}&surname=${surname}&birth=${birth}&eMail=${eMail}`;
return this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOtions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

the file posting method:
  public postFile(formData: FormData): Observable<any>{
const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/file/`;
return this.http.post(url+`/Upload`, formData);

}
From Postman everything works. I suspect the problem is the two different @CrossOrigin annotations that contains the same URL.
What am I doing wrong?
Can you please help me?
If you need some other piece of code please ask and I'll post it.

if the problem that from the frontend endpoint and port you can't get any result or data from tha backend then as i think there's a solution for this by adding this code to your backendApplication file
|-- Application
|   |-- controller
|   |-- Entity
|   |-- DTO
|   |-- BackendApplication.jav
here is the code =>
@Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
      CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
      corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
            "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
      corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
      corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
      UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
      urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
      return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
  }

don't forgot this annotation @Bean

Thank you. It also works for Post requests right?

OK, i have also 2 different applications (one for one endpoint, another one for the other). Should i put this code in both applications?

if they share the same backend and different frontend so all you have to do is too add the url of the second frontend with its port like this
corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:4200"));

It must work for all method types.
Here, we specify the types of methods it should work with:
corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));

Thank you, It worked, altho i get 404 now. I also noticed the post method in the backend does not work.
